# What is the power unit of the world background emission

Tags: lighting

In Brecht https://devtalk.blender.org/t/cycles-unit-of-light-energy-attn-brecht/12456 stated:

"Note that most lights in Cycles use Watts, since what is specified is the total energy emitted over the entire area of the light in all directions. The total energy does not change if you scale the light. It is however modulated by color and shaders so the effective Watts will be typically be lower unless that’s purely (1,1,1).

It’s W/(m^2) for sun light and W/(m^2 . sr) for emission values in (surface) materials"

So what is the unit the of world background emission.

Comment: Not sure how helpful it will be (compared to what you already know) - but this page seems to have some rather useful information on the subject - https://blendergrid.com/learn/articles/cycles-physically-correct-brightness